# how to instantiate a browser already available using watir 6.xxx in ruby?

Tags: ruby, watir, instantiation, watir-classic

how to instantiate a browser already available using watir 6.xxx in ruby?

I tested with "watir-classic" and ran, the problem that the whole design was written using watir 6.xx.

Comment: That feature has been deprecated. You can only interact with a browser window that has been created by the current Ruby session. For simple cases I use irb to switch between code and manual browser interaction. For complex cases I use debug points with RubyMine (pry is also an option).

Comment: @titusfortner, when you mention the feature being deprecated, do you mean the Watir feature? Some of the browsers, [at least Chrome](https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2017/09/15/attach-to-a-manually-opened-chrome-browser-using-debuggeraddress/), do support some limited attachment capability. Or do you mean that Chromedriver is going to deprecate the capability?

Comment: I'm just saying that Watir used to support it when it was based on the old Windows COM functionality, but now that Watir is based on Selenium, it is reliant on Selenium to support it, which it does not. I don't believe it is a technical limitation, and the w3c allows for it (https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#h-note12), but nothing is there for Watir to hook into at this time.

Comment: @leandropessoa, can you expand on what your use case is? For example, my Watir-Classic tests used to `attach` to popup windows. The solution there was to switch to using `window(locator).use`. In contrast, for my manual testing, I actually did need to `attach` since I was always opening/closing tabs. If the latter, it would help to know what browsers you need, since as mentioned in the above comments, the availability is browser dependent.

Comment: Thank you for replying.
my problem is that the desktop application that I'm testing calls the IE page, in which case I need to fill in some information on it. In this same project we tested another WEB application and we used watir 6.XX.
So I need some method similar to the "attach" from "watir-classic" to "watir 6.xxx". (Watir :: Browser.attach (: url, /http://XXX.XXXX.XXXXX/)).
Sorry for my English.

Comment: @Justin Ko, I tried using browser.window (locator), browser.windows [x] but without success, it seems that this method only identifies daughters pages of the browser that is instantiated

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you might be out of luck for IE. At the moment, you will need to continue using Watir-Classic.